# Phonon::VideoPlayer Qt 4.8.6

Tags: qt, video, video-player, phonon

Hi I have a problem with Phonon and a slot, it's me first try with this and I hope you could help me,

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <phonon/VideoPlayer>
#include <phonon/VideoWidget>
#include <phonon/MediaObject>
#include <phonon/MediaSource>
#include <phonon>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QUrl>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
QPushButton *quit;
QPushButton *addFile;
QWidget *Main;
Phonon::VideoPlayer *player;
public slots:

    void startVideo();

};
```

my header ^

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
Main = new QWidget;
addFile = new QPushButton("Dodaj Plik");
quit = new QPushButton("Zamknij");
player = new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory, Main);
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(addFile);
    layout->addWidget(quit);
    layout->addWidget(player);
Main->setWindowTitle("Phonon");
Main->setLayout(layout);
Main->setGeometry(550, 312, 640, 480);
Main->show();
QObject::connect(addFile, SIGNAL(clicked()), player, SLOT(startVideo()));
QObject::connect(quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), Main, SLOT(close()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
void MainWindow::startVideo()
{
QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("odtworz film"));
player->play(file);
}
```

source ^

For now application runs without problems but when I click "dodaj plik" nothing happens and debugger says it have no such a slot like `startVideo()`

Can you help me to figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you establish connection like this:

```
QObject::connect(addFile, SIGNAL(clicked()), player, SLOT(startVideo()));
```

however your `startVideo()` slot defined in the `MainWindow` class. Thus, the correct connection should look like:

```
connect(addFile, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startVideo()));
```

The `QObject::` prefix is not needed, as the `QMainWindow` - the base class, already is `QObject`.